# Transparent background and top window border in a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to make a splash screen with a png.
I use Python 3.7.4 64-bit, under macOS 10.14.4 and Visual Code 1.33.1

With root.overrideredirect(True) no windows are displayed.
With root.overrideredirect(False) the png is correctly displayed but the top window border is visible.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
# Hide the root window drag bar and close button
root.overrideredirect(True)
# Make the root window always on top
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', True)
# Turn off the window shadow
root.wm_attributes('-transparent', True)
# Set the root window background color to a transparent color
root.config(bg='systemTransparent')

root.geometry('+300+300')

# Store the PhotoImage to prevent early garbage collection
root.image = tk.PhotoImage(file='./local/pics/splash.png')
# Display the image on a label
label = tk.Label(root, image=root.image)
# Set the label background color to a transparent color
label.config(bg='systemTransparent')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: with root.overrideredirect(False)]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This will hide the title bar

and fixates your window to top always:

```
root.attributes('-type', 'dock')
```

If you don't need it at the top:

```
root.attributes('-type', 'splash')
```

This will hide the title bar

If this can be improved please comment.

Comment: Maybe that's works fine under windows os, but on macOS arguments are different. https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/wm+attributes . What do you think ?

Comment: try appending `wm_` and see if it works, on linux also these work. wm is window manager I guess it should work without them too.

Comment: @Jamyz just checked, it works with both `.wm_attributes` and only `.attributes`. Hope it cleared your doubts.\

Comment: I have the same error  '''bad attribute "-type": must be -alpha, -fullscreen, -modified, -notify, -titlepath, -topmost, or -transparent'''. Can you send me the code you are use ? Where you got 'splash' and 'dock'